# SmartGWT Object binding without specifying object's fields

Tags: gwt, data-binding, smartgwt

I am just wondering if it's possible to create some sort of binding without explicitly specifying all of the fields that need to be mapped to some widget(i.e. ListGrid).

Currently I do the following: First I read all the JSON objects fields and put these fields into CategoryRecord object like this:

```
        public class CategoryRecord extends Record {

                public CategoryRecord(String displayName, String id) {
                    setDisplayName(displayName);
                    setId(id);
                }

                private void setId(String id) {
                    setAttribute("id", id);

                }

                public String getId() {
                    return getAttributeAsString("id");
                }
    private void setDisplayName(String displayName) {
            setAttribute("displayName", displayName);

        }

        public String getDisplayName() {
            return getAttributeAsString("displayName");
        }
 }
```

Then I return a CategoryRecord[] object and put it into a ListGrid. But what if application developers decide to change the "id" field to "categoryId" or completely remove it. Do I have to manually change my code each time something like this happens? Or is there a way to get the whole JSON object, get it's fields and put it wherever I want, without specifying their names.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Just iterate over the properties of the JSON object and create ListGridField objects for each one.